# Entity object to array

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to convert an entity to a associative array.
It seems that the method `toArray()` is not available for entity objects.

Reading Symfony doc, it seems I should use the `SerializerInterface`.
After enabling it, I can't seems to find the right syntax to convert my entity into an associative array.

Can someone correct my code please?

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

// -----------------------

public function salleAction(Request $request, Projet $projet, SerializerInterface $serializer) {
    return this->json(array(
        'projet'=>$serializer->serialize($projet, new ObjectNormalizer())
    ));
}
```

With the code above, I'm getting this error message

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

If I replace `new ObjectNormalizer()` by `'jsons'`, I'm getting the next error message:

> A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "AppBundle\Entity\Projet" (configured limit: 1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to add the following method to an object, that needs to be converted

```
public function toArray()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

and use it everywhere `$array = $projet->toArray();`

Comment: It's working, but some things aren't "right". First, Datetime and properties on the owning side (entity relations) are objects instead of simple value. Second, properties on the inverse side are included as emtpy object, I would like to exclude them. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: this is just a basic example, you are able to customize this method for your specific need, that's why I suggested to attach the method to a an entity, because the method is specific for each particular case.